# Speed Up XML Queries in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, xml, performance

I store all my data in on XML column in SQL Server 2005.

As more and more records are being inserted, I notice the queries are slowing down.  I've tried creaeting a Primary XML Index, as well as a Secondary VALUE index and this did not do anything to help the speed.

Any tips,thoughts, or tricks that I'm missing?

Sample View that I query:

```
SELECT Id
, CaseNumber
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/StartDate)[1]', 'varchar(25)') + ' ' + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/StartTime)[1]', 'varchar(25)') as StartDate
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/@Status)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as [Status]
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/PatrolDistrict/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as PatrolDistrict
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/PrimaryUnit/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(40)') as PrimaryUnit
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/@StreetNumber)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' ' + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/@StreetName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' ' + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/StreetSuffix/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' ' + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/@City)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' ' + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/State/@Abbreviation)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + ' '  + XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Address/@ZipCode)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Location
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/ReportType/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as ReportType
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/Offenses/OffenseDescription/OffenseType/@CodeAndDescription)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as IncidentType
, XmlTest as Report
, CreatedBy as UserId
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/PrimaryUnit/@ID)[1]', 'integer') as UnitId
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/PrimaryUnit/@Code)[1]', 'varchar(6)') as UnitCode
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/Owner/AgencyID)[1]', 'char(2)') as AgencyId   
, IsLocked
, LockedBy
, XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/VersionUsed)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as VersionUsed
FROM UploadReport
WHERE XmlTest.value('(/CodeFiveReport/Owner/AgencyID)[1]', 'char(2)') = '06'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to drastically speed up my query using two subqueries then parsing the XML from that result set.

Comment: you can speed it up a little more, see my reply

Comment: @mint, can you explain how you did it?

Answer (score 5):

The query suffered from a performance issue only when the results were used in an insert into a table or a join. Simply returning the values from the select in management studio was nearly instant. Prefix that with an `INSERT INTO` and it would take over 30 seconds for the same work.

After adding `/text()` such as

```
from @list.nodes('/List/Id/text()') as C(C)
```

instead of what I had:

```
from @list.nodes('/List/Id') as C(C)
```

This brought the query back to a zero-second execution even with the insert.

Answer (score 4):

Read [XML Best Practices for Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms345115)

The two tips I recall the most making a difference in speead are

- Use `node/text()` instead of just `node` for your xpaths.
- Try never to use `../` in your xpath expressions, as it slows it down **SIGNIFICANTLY**

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but I don't think any of those tips help the above query!  Is returning a singleton via value the most effecient way to query?

Comment: @mint, in cases like `(/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/StartDate)[1]` you could add the `/text()` to the xpath, and it should improve performance slightly.  I've seen 15 minute queries reduced to seconds because of little things like adding `/text()` to the xpath and/or removing any occurrences of `../`.  You don't use it for `@attributes` though, as they are already text.  It's just that with `/CodeFiveReport/ReportEvent/StartDate` sql server doesn't know if it's getting a node back, that it has to convert to text, or text.  With `/text()` it doesn't have to do that check.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to speed up a query from running in 4 minutes 30 seconds to 20 seconds by using some tips from:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/06/23/sql-server-2005-xquery-performance-tips.aspx

I had this:

```
SELECT
Package.query('(/D/D[@n="Main"]/node()[@n="FirstNames"]/text())[1]') as [Main.FirstNames],
Package.query('(/D/D[@n="Main"]/node()[@n="LastName"]/text())[1]') as [Main.LastName],
```

... lots more columns

Changing to this made all the difference:

```
SELECT
Package.query('(/D[1]/D[@n="Main"][1]/node()[@n="FirstNames"][1]/text())[1]') as [Main.FirstNames],
Package.query('(/D[1]/D[@n="Main"][1]/node()[@n="LastName"][1]/text())[1]') as [Main.LastName],
```

... lots more columns

By the look of your above query this might have helped you as well.